# Sys.Application.add_init Not Invoked on UpdatePanel Update

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a custom UI control which has a JavaScript class written around the AJAX.NET framework.  It inherits from the Sys.UI.Control.  The control itself is a UserControl.  In the render method I wrap the control in a span and give the span's id the ClientID of the user control.  This way I can do this later on:

```
var control = $find('<%= ServerControlID.ClientID %>');
```

This allows me to get the client object that represents the UI control.

I create the control in Javascript by doing this (also in the render method)

```
writer.Write(@"<script type='text/javascript'>
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
debugger;
    $create(General.Filters.AccountGroupFilter,
        " + GetProperties() + @",
        null,
        null,
        $get('" + this.ClientID + @"'));
});
</script>");
```

This creates the object.  It's done inside of the init event of the life cycle.

The problem is that this control is wrapped inside of an UpdatePanel by a consuming page/control.  When another control initiates an update all the controls' UIs get redrawn, BUT the init event NEVER FIRES again.

What happens then is when I do this:

```
var control = $find('<%= ServerControlID.ClientID %>');
if(control != null)
  control.doSomething();
```

Nothing happens because the $find does not find the control after the AJAX call.  I know I'm NOT doing this correctly.  Where am I going wrong.  The MSDN article for this stuff is pointing me in circles!

EDIT: Figured I'd include the Render method that I'm doing in the UserControl.cs portion

```
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write("<span id=\"" + this.ClientID + "\" >");
        writer.Write(@"<script type='text/javascript'>
        Sys.Application.add_init(function() {

        $create(TradePMR.OMS.Resources.UserControls.General.Filters.AccountGroupFilter,
        " + GetProperties() + @",
        null,
        null,
        $get('" + this.ClientID + @"'));
        });
        </script>");

        base.Render(writer);
        writer.WriteEndTag("span");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write all that `Sys.Application.add_init` stuff yourself; implement `IScriptControl` as per [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386403.aspx).

The key is the part about `RegisterScriptControl` and `RegisterScriptDescriptors`, which registers your control with the `ScriptManager` so that an async postback will recreate your client control as necessary.

As a footnote, there is a [seperate but similar article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386403.aspx) if you are implementing `Sys.UI.Behavior` instead.